# Unable to retrieve values from Axios Response data

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

```html
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    id: Number,
  },

  data () {
    return {
      password: null,
      loading: true,
      errored: false
    }
  },
  created () {
    axios
      .get('http://localhost:3000/users?filter[where][id]=' + this.id)
      .then(response => {
        this.password = response.data.password
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
        this.errored = true
      })
      .finally(() => this.loading = false)
  }
}
</script>
```

The above is the code in question, i'm simply trying to retrieve a current user's password as plain text.
(It's for a University Project, and I need to display the user's password hash as text to prove it's hashed).

The above code will return this array in dev tools:

```js
[ 
  { 
    "id": 1, 
    "user": "SomeUsername", 
    "password": "SomePasswordHash" 
  } 
]
}
```

However, If I run that code as whole, it will not return anything when using:

```html
{{ this.password }}
```

I have no idea why this is.

Edit:

If I change password to info, and then this.info = response.data, then access that array via this.info[0].password it works, however when I refresh I'll get this error: Cannot read properties of null (reading '0').

Comment: Is your api sending the correct data as json body? Can you see the response in your browser developer tools?

Comment: Yes, it's a response built from a repository within Loopback4.

Comment: Please share here the response that your API show in your Browser Developer Tools

Comment: you do not need 'this' in the handlebars.

Comment: `Cannot read properties of null (reading '0')` is coming from the fact that you do have a reference to something that is null at the beginning (in your template) and populated later on. Hence, you cannot `null[0]` or `undefined[0]` something. You could make a conditional with a `v-if` and check if the actual value is populated, thay way you will not get the exception.